# C# clipboard direct copy paste

Tags: c#, windows

Hi

I want to make direct copy/paste so for example I just make one click to button direct will make the paste to clipboard for this you can write example code

Comment: where you copying from? is it a textbox?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to copy from a textbox (in this example textBox1), this is what you need:

```
Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text); //To copy your text to your clipboard
Clipboard.GetText(); //To get your text from your clipboard
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

> Clipboard.SetText("your Text")

to Put Text to Clipboard

and

> String myText = Clipboard.GetText()

to recieve Text from Your Keyboard.

Comment: ı want just make one click copy/paste direct to clipboard all files

Comment: @fatin53: Yeah, and `Clipboard.GetText()` and `Clipboard.SetText(string text)` will do the trick. We're not here to write your code for you. If you want a ready-to-go program, you should ask on [the programmers site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For Listbox:

```
myListbox.Items.Add(Clipboard.GetText());
```

Comment: ı make this with code direct copy but have one problem ı copy write too listbox (collection) this resolved foreach loop how ı take with file name to listbox