# Get selection of any window c# .net 4.8 WPF

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

So my current project is comming to an end.

But I have an issue, i need to get a selection from any window and insert that into my current method, and then paste a new string into the selection.

This means that if i mark the following "This is a simple line", and i press my shortcut, i want "This is a simple line" to go into my method, and transform the text to "This line is more advanced", when i press my global hotkey.

Currently the method takes a string and returns a string (So the method works fine), i just need for it to copy the selection, do the method and then paste the new text, when i use my shortcut.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to have the Windows handle of the dialog and control for which you want to get and set the text, and then use the Windows API [to get and set the selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251578/how-do-i-get-the-selected-text-from-the-focused-window-using-native-win32-api) by emulating Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it, the "fix" was just to simulate/emulate the "ctrt + c" "ctrl + v" shortcut in the project. I've gotten my inspiration from: This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLxqoh1JLnM). Big thanks to "Matthew Watson" for the suggestion

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text); //To copy your text to your clipboard
Clipboard.GetText(); //To get your text from your clipboard
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10140582/12345062

Comment: `textbox1.Text` assumes that the OP "owns" the application to copy from. That's not the case as far as I can tell.

Comment: "i need to get a selection from any window"

Comment: ok got it. You want to create some service that can access other windows and selected text. even if you are able to create that service you will not able to use Clipboard from service.

Comment: Yes, i want to get a text selection from ex. chrome